# Configuring trusted-host for setuptools

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

When I call `pip install` for a PyPI repository with an untrusted certificate, I can skip SSL verification by using --trusted-host option:

```
$ pip install googleapis-common-protos --index-url https://maven.mycompany.org/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/simple --trusted-host maven.mycompany.org
Looking in indexes: https://maven.mycompany.org/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/simple
Collecting googleapis-common-protos
  Downloading https://maven.mycompany.org/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/packages/61/29/1549f61917eadd11650e42b78b4afcfe9cb467157af4510ab8cb59535f14/googleapis-common-protos-1.5.6.tar.gz
...
Installing collected packages: googleapis-common-protos
Successfully installed googleapis-common-protos-1.5.6
```

However, when using setuptools, I see no option to configure it:

```
$ python setup.py test
running pytest
Searching for googleapis-common-protos==1.5.3
Reading https://maven.mycompany.org/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/simple/googleapis-common-protos/
Authenticating as uploader for https://maven.mycompany.org/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/simple/googleapis-common-protos/ (from .pypirc)
Download error on https://maven.mycompany.org/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/simple/googleapis-common-protos/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726) -- Some packages may not be found!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setuptools` uses [easy_install](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html) under the hood, and `easy_install` doesn't have such option. See

```
python setup.py easy_install --help
```

`--trusted-host` is only available with `pip`.

Comment: So how I can I disable SSL cert validation with easy_install?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.